# Restore database window won't resize

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I can't seem to find the option to resize the window in SQL Server 2012. I can resize it sideways but I'm unable to resize it other than that. There is also no bar at the side for me to scroll down. I can't view the buttons at the bottom. I already tried googling the solution and no result was found.

Please see a screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Are you using the SQL 2012 version of SSMS? The window is resizable in the current SSMS version (18.8) and can be used with SQL 2012.

Comment: yes, but i cant resize it to show the buttons below, i can only resize it sideways.

Comment: As Dan mentioned. Download and install the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).  The issue is high DPI displays - this is fixed in the latest version.  NOTE that SSMS is only a client tool and is in no way tied to the specific version of SQL Server that you connect to.  Your other option is to open a query window and use the ```RESTORE DATABASE ``` command (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15 for syntax) to complete the restore.